# Imap strange behavior when fetch UIDS greater than

Tags: imap

I try to get uids from imap server which are greater than specific uid in Inbox folder.

The query looks like:

```
UID SEARCH UID 13780:*
```

Response:

```
* SEARCH 13779
aaaj OK UID SEARCH Completed.
```

Why does it return UID 13779 ? It less than 13780!

Then I send email and the response is the following:

```
* SEARCH 13779
* 5 EXISTS
* 4 RECENT
aaak OK UID SEARCH Completed.
```

And after next request the response is the following:

```
* SEARCH 13780
aaal OK UID SEARCH Completed.
```

Why does it happens so ?

During all requests I keep session opened.

Why it returned lower uid I have understood, because max uid was lower than requested uid. But why does it returns first time this one:

```
* 5 EXISTS
* 4 RECENT
```

And then:

```
* SEARCH 13780
aaal OK UID SEARCH Completed.
```

So 13780 is needed information in my case, can I get it at once ? Without EXISTS and RECENT in first query ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UID SEARCH UID 13780:*` does not mean "all UIDs greater than or equal to 13780".  It means "all UIDs between 13780 and the largest UID in the mailbox".  That is, the `*` is internally replaced with the current largest UID.

If the current largest UID is 13779, then the command is parsed to `UID SEARCH UID 13780:13779`, which is equivalent to `UID SEARCH UID 13779:13780`, as by specification ranges `m:n` and `n:m` are equivalent.

Therefore, you always get the largest UID in the mailbox.

Comment: And this scenario can easily happend if your code delete messages, and then wants to continue from the last processed uid. If that one was deleted, the newest highest one is lower that what your code has 'bookmarked'.